# Why is cin.ignore() necessary when using "getline" after "cin", but is not required when using "cin" multiple times?

Tags: c++, cin, getline

In my knowledge when using `getline()` after `cin`, we need to flush the newline character in the buffer first, before calling `getline()`, and we do this by calling `cin.ignore()`.

```
std::string name, address;

std::cin >> name;
std::cin.ignore(); //flush newline character
getline(std::cin,address);
```

But when using multiple `cin`, we do not need to flush the newline character.

```
std::string firstname, lastname;

std::cin >> firstname;
std::cout << firstname << std::endl;

//no need to flush newline character

std::cin >> lastname;
std::cout << lastname << std::endl;
```

Why is that? Why is `cin.ignore()` necessary in the first case, but not the last?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `getline()` reads **until the next newline** character from the given `std::istream`, while `std::istream::operator>>()` **skips** any whitespaces (Spaces, Tabs and *newlines*).

So when you read an integer or a floating point number, all trailing whitespaces are left in the input stream. When you read from a console or terminal, you type the data and hit Enter, the latter of which is left in the stream, and will be caught by `getline()` if you don't clear it.

You don't have to clear it because the next time you read a `std::string`, `std::istream::operator>>()` skips the whitespaces for you.

---

Consider this code segment;

```
std::string a, b;
std::cin >> a;
std::getline(std::cin, b);
```

and this input:

```
Stack Overflow<Enter>
Where developers learn.<Enter>
```

The first `cin` statement will read the word `Stack`, leaving a space and `Overflow<Enter>` behind. Then it'll be read by `getline`, so

```
assert(b == " Overflow");
```

If you insert a `std::cin.ignore()` before calling `getline()`, it will instead turn into

```
assert(b == "Where developers learn.");
```

Comment: @Duthomhas Could you please clarify what do you mean by _including char_? Do you mean that the `>>` operator can also skip some characters?

Comment: @UzairZia When you read a character with `>>`, you won't be able to catch whitespaces unless you modify some settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
signed main(){
    /*
     * input is of next two lines
     * Stack Overflow<Enter>
     * Where developers learn.<Enter>
     * for more about cin.ignore visit http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/
     */
    string name, address;
    cin>>name;
    //cin.ignore();
    //cin.ignore(256,'\n');
    getline(cin,address);
    cout << address << endl;
    assert(address == " Overflow"); // breaks if using cin.ignore() or cin.ignore(256,'\n')
    assert(address == "Overflow"); // breaks if using cin.ignore(256,'\n') OR not using any
    assert(address == "Where developers learn."); // breaks if using cin.ignore() or not using ignore
}
```

enter the input

> Stack Overflow
>
> Where developers learn.